# Type script react Json array formatting to display

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, typescript

This is data stored in database

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "item": {
      "title": "City1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "item": {
      "title": "City2"
    }
  }
]
```

now this data is present in `city`  in props.

Now data is present in state loading it from database in react

```
interface itemType { title: string };
```

Declared interface for formatting data in string,
I want to show only title in string format expected.

I'm writing a function like this.

```
private loadData = () => {
        interface itemType { title: string };   
        const titleArray: [itemType] = [];
        const { city} = this.props;
        city.source.isComplete ? city.source.value.map((item) => {
            titleArray.push({ title: item.title })

        }) : [];
    }
```

Help me converting this into string as asked above. Thanks.

I just want to get the title out from that JSON array and store it in variable.
How can I do that? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could map your fetched data directly :

```
const titleArray: [itemType] = city.source.value.map(item => item.title);
```

Comment: Type 'Value<string>[]' is not assignable to type '[itemType]'.
  Property '0' is missing in type 'Value<string>[]'. This error occur.

Comment: Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[itemType]'.
  Property '0' is missing in type '[]'. and this too

Comment: Why aren't you using an array of `strings` ? instead of `itemType`